# How can I automatically mark all opened files for delete when they are manually deleted from workspace

Tags: version-control, perforce, p4v

Following scenario:

first I open all project files for edit with

```
p4 edit ...
```

then several files are manually deleted from a Perforce workspace directory (not with `p4 delete` command).

How do I mark all the deleted files as deleted in a changelist?

If to compare with Git I'm looking for a command like:

```
git add --all *
```

Question concerns `p4` or/and `p4v`, I know that `p4eclipse` has this feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run:

```
p4 reconcile
```

In P4V the equivalent is "Reconcile Offline Work..."

Comment: `p4 reconcile` works when a deleted file wasn't open. However in my scenario I first open all the project files and then delete some of them (via IDE). In this case reconcile returns `No file(s) to reconcile.`

Comment: upvoted since this solution works fine in case if file is not opened for edit

Comment: Check out change #841159 in http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/user/relnotes.txt, then upgrade.  :)  In previous releases, an easy workaround is to do "p4 revert -k" before "p4 reconcile".

Comment: Upgrade is not an option, however `revert -k` looks promising. I'll check it in  a few hours when I'll be back to work.